# multiplication Ordered Pair Problem (counting)

Tags: combinatorics

We will call $(a, b, c)\in\mathbb{N}^3$ multiplication pair if $ab=c$ or $bc=a$ or $ca=b$. For example, $(1, 1, 1), (6, 2, 3), (2, 8, 4), (5, 5, 25)$ is "multiplication pair." The problem is to count the number of function $f:\{1, 2, \cdots, 12\}\rightarrow\{1, 2, \cdots, 12\}$ that satisfies the condition: if $(a, b, c)$ is "multiplication pair," $(f(a), f(b), f(c))$ is also multiplication pair.

I have no idea on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. Have you written down all the possible multiplication pairs? (There aren't too many of them).
2. Of those, how many have a 1 in them? What does that tell you about where 1 has to map?
3. Now look at the rest. Can you figure out the possible images of 2 and 3 under $f$?
4. From there, I think it's just a bit of case management, but I haven't worked out the details.